# CLGeocoding, facing problem when reverse geocode and getting the address from LAT LONG to show in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reverse-geocoding

I am new swift. I have a task that need to complete. I am getting response from server, where I get numbers of Latitude and Longitude.

```
    {
        EndLat = "28.511593";
        EndtLong = "77.071136";
    },
    {
        EndLat = "28.511593";
        EndtLong = "77.071136";
    },.....
```

getting this type of response having more than 100s of entry.

Now when I'm fetching the address through reverse geocoding..

```
func getAddressForLogOut(pdblLatitude: String, withLongitude pdblLongitude: String) {

            if (pdblLatitude != "") && (pdblLongitude != "") {

                var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                let lat: Double = Double("\(pdblLatitude)")!
                //21.228124
                let lon: Double = Double("\(pdblLongitude)")!
                //72.833770
                let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
                center.latitude = lat
                center.longitude = lon

                let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)

                ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
                    {(placemarks, error) in
                        if (error != nil)
                        {
                            print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

                        if pm.count > 0 {
                            let pm = placemarks![0]
                            print(pm.country)
                            print(pm.locality)
                            print(pm.subLocality)
                            print(pm.thoroughfare)
                            print(pm.postalCode)
                            print(pm.subThoroughfare)
                            var addressString : String = ""
                            if pm.subLocality != nil {
                                addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + ", "
                            }
                            if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                                addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                            }
                            if pm.locality != nil {
                                addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
                            }
                            if pm.country != nil {
                                addressString = addressString + pm.country! + ", "
                            }
                            if pm.postalCode != nil {
                                addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
                            }
                            print(addressString)
                            self.endAdd = addressString
                            print("self.endAdd is",self.endAdd)
                        }
                } )
            }
        }
```

I'm using that function in tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath functon. when i scroll the table view the app get crash. getting nil at placemark!

let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark] at this line.

Can any help me to use the reverse geocoding that let me fetching the address of more than 100s of latitude and longitude and show it up in tableView.

Comment: what crash ////// ?

Comment: getting nil in placemarks

let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

at this line

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: You cannot call your method in cellForRow. Your method is asynchronous. The cell has already been returned before the geocoding happens.

Answer (score -1):

CLGeocoder returns an optional type:

```
typealias CLGeocodeCompletionHandler = ([CLPlacemark]?, Error?) -> Void
```

(from [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocodecompletionhandler))

you should check it.

I think that usage a cell for data loading from geocoder is bad idea, because you will have a race:

1. start request1(lat1,lon1)
2. reusing cell
3. start request2(lat2,lon2)
4. response from geocoder for request1

At 4) a cell shows inconsistent data.